# CODI with ejb stateless on Websphere liberty profile 8.5.5

Tags: websphere-liberty, codi

I cannot launch a webapp that embedd CODI on websphere liberty profile 8.5.5 if the webapp contains a @Stateless ejb.

I get this exception:

```
[ERROR   ] null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] An error occured while initializing MyFaces: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
    Faces Servlet
    codiTest
    javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ApplicationScoped does not exist within current thread
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:342)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.config.CodiCoreConfig_$$_javassist_78.isAdvancedQualifierRequiredForDependencyInjection(CodiCoreConfig_$$_javassist_78.java)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.listener.phase.PhaseListenerExtension.consumePhaseListeners(PhaseListenerExtension.java:110)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleFactoryWrapper.getLifecycle(CodiLifecycleFactoryWrapper.java:67)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:322)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:385)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ApplicationScoped does not exist within current thread
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:342)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.config.CodiCoreConfig_$$_javassist_78.isAdvancedQualifierRequiredForDependencyInjection(CodiCoreConfig_$$_javassist_78.java)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.listener.phase.PhaseListenerExtension.consumePhaseListeners(PhaseListenerExtension.java:110)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleFactoryWrapper.getLifecycle(CodiLifecycleFactoryWrapper.java:67)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:322)
    ... 1 more

[WARNING ] Unknown RenderKit 'HTML_BASIC'.
[WARNING ] Unknown RenderKit 'HTML_BASIC'.
[ERROR   ] An exception occurred
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a RenderKit for "HTML_BASIC"
```

I've constated that the problem occurs only if an ejb is present in the project (in my case a @Stateless ejb).

In this case, the application context is initialized when the server is started and the webapp installed/deployed. No problem here.

When the first HTTP request is handled by the webapp, the `FacesServlet` is initialized and `CodiNavigationHandler` is instanciated.

The method `CodiNavigationHandler.isAddViewConfigsAsNavigationCaseActivated()` is called in the constructor and tries to get a reference on CODI `JsfModuleConfig`. This `JsfModuleConfig` has an @ApplicationScoped annotation and the the beanManager tries to get the application context.

This application context has already been created (when the webapp is deployed) but the `LibertyContextsService.initApplicationContext(String)`has not been called yet.
So the application context is null on the `LibertyContextsService.applicationContexts` ThreadLocal variable and the error occurs:

```
WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ApplicationScoped does not exist within current thread
```

To reproduce:

- create a Dynamic Web Project
- add an almost empty beans.xml under WEB-INF (just a `beans` element)
- add an almost empty faces-config.xml under WEB-INF (just a `faces-config` element)
- add a web.xml with a faces/index.xhtml
- copy codi jars in WEB-INF/lib (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/myfaces-extcdi-assembly-jsf20-1.0.5-bin.zip)
- add a stateless bean:

  ```
  import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;

  @Stateless
  public class MyBean {

      @PostConstruct
      public void postConstruct() {
          System.out.println("post construct: " + this);
      }

      public String getTitle() {
          return "test";
      }
  }
  ```
- add a jsf bean:

  ```
  import javax.inject.Inject;
  import javax.inject.Named;

  @Named
  public class MyController {

      @Inject
      private MyBean myBean;

      public String getTitle() {
          return myBean.getTitle();
      }
  }
  ```
- add a simple jsf web page with:

  ```
  <h:body>
      <h:outputText>${myController.title}</h:outputText>
  </h:body>
  ```

**nota**: if you remove the @stateless on the ejb, the application works.

Comment: This is probably a product issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively it seems to be a bug (I also post the question on IBM forums: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f372bbc5-5ba4-4c2a-9ef0-0bdcd76766da#09228314-2baf-4892-899e-5a8cc52daa19).

I'm going to try to find a way to create a PMR (I'm in a big company, difficult to find the right person that will grant me access to that).

So for now, I've switched to jboss.

Comment: Do you get some answer on your PMR? Maybe i ran into the same issue.